# Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?

Tags: c#, отладка, обработка-ошибок, c#-faq

Здравствуйте!

Я занимаюсь разработкой и когда пишу код, то он иногда не работает так, как
я задумывал или даже вообще не работает. Сижу и смотрю на него, гадаю: что и где не так?

Не могу усидеть - иду сразу на ресурсы профессионалов, например *Stack Overflow* и публикую вопрос  *"Где здесь ошибка?"* или *"Почему не работает?"*

Но оказывается часто, что проблема мелкая: дурацкая опечатка, ошибка в синтаксисе или еще какая мелочь. Профессионалом так не станешь, если по каждой ерунде бегать по ресурсам. А я хочу им быть.

**Вопрос**: какие есть способы, чтобы найти ошибки в коде на *C#*? Какие есть инструменты, методы  и т.д.?

Спасибо.

Comment: уже по чеивертому языку, за последние 2 дня. Видать сильно бомбануло =) Но вещь полезная =)

Comment: @LexHobbit да, это серия  ̶к̶н̶и̶г̶  вопросов, посвященные нахождению ошибок. Полный список, при желании, будет пополняться: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701489/191482

Comment: я бы присоединился и написал в таком же стиле под Android, golang и python =)

Comment: А у нас нигде нет эталонного ответа в git про то, что это тоже способ нахождения (локализации) ошибок? Наверняка Волынкин что-то писал на эту тему.

Comment: Ну вот зачем здесь эти "Здравствуйте" и "Спасибо"? Чтобы вопрос больше походил на вопрос от нуба что ли?

Comment: @AK через `git bisect`? Или просто ресетнуть к последнему рабочему состоянию?

Comment: @NickVolynkin а я что-то так и не догоняю, за что минуса-то?

Comment: @LexHobbit я тоже. Может быть, за стиль.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Вчера всё работало, а сегодня не работает / Код не работает как задумано

или

## Debugging (Отладка)

---

В чем заключается процесс отладки? Что это такое?

**Процесс отладки состоит в том, что мы останавливаем выполнения скрипта в любом месте, смотрим, что находится в переменных, в функциях, анализируем и переходим в другие места; ищем те места, где поведение отклоняется от правильного.**

*Заметка:* Отладка производится как правило в **IDE (Интегрированная среда разработки)**. Что это такое можно чуть подробнее ознакомиться в вопросе

#### [Какие есть способы предупреждения ошибок, их нахождения и устранения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701818/191482)

В данном случае будет рассмотрен пример с *Visual Studio*, но отладить код можно и в любой другой *IDE*.

---

### **Подготовка**

Достаточно иметь в наличии *IDE*, например *Visual Studio*

### **Запуск**

Для начала в левой части панели с кодом на любой строке можно кликнуть <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>, тем самым поставив точку останова (breakpoint - брейкпойнт). Это то место, где отладчик автоматически остановит выполнение *C#*, как только до него дойдёт. Количество breakpoint'ов не ограничено. Можно ставить везде и много.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отладка запускается сочетанием <kbd>F5</kbd> или выбором в верхнем меню `Debug` → `Start Debugging`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае, т.к. функция вызывается сразу на той же странице, то при нажатии кнопки `Debug` — отладчик моментально вызовет метод, выполнение "заморозится" на первом же брейкпойнте. В ином случае, для активации требуется исполнить действие, при котором произойдет исполнение нужного участка кода (клик на кнопку в UI, передача POST запроса с данными и прочие другие действия)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цифрами обозначены:

1. Стэк  вызовов, все вложенные вызовы, которые привели к текущему месту кода.
2. Переменные. На текущий момент строки ниже номера 8 ещё не выполнилась, поэтому определена лишь `data` и `numsStringArr`
3. Показывает текущие значения любых переменных и выражений. В любой момент здесь можно вписать имя любой переменной в поле `name` и посмотреть её значение в реальном времени. Например `data` или `nums[0]`, а можно и `nums[i]` и `item.test.data.name[5].info[key[1]]` и т.д. На текущий момент строки ниже номера 24 ещё не выполнилась, поэтому `num` (которая появляется лишь в цикле `foreach`) во вкладке `Watch` обозначена красным цветом с надписью "The name 'num' does not exist in the current context".

### **Процесс**

Для самого процесса используются **элементы управления** (см. изображение выше, выделено зеленым прямоугольником)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Show Next Statement (<kbd>Alt+Num *</kbd>) — переносит в файл и текущую линию отлаживаемого скрипта. Например если файлов много, решили посмотреть что в других вкладках, а потом забыли где у вас отладка :)

Step Over (<kbd>F10</kbd>) — делает один шаг не заходя внутрь функции. Т.е. если на текущей линии есть какая-то функция, а не просто переменная со значением, то при клике данной кнопки, отладчик не будет заходить внутрь неё.

Step Into (<kbd>F11</kbd>) —  делает шаг. Но в отличие от предыдущей, если есть вложенный вызов (например функция), то заходит внутрь неё.

Step Out (<kbd>Shift+F11</kbd>) — выполняет команды до завершения текущей функции. Удобна, если случайно вошли во вложенный вызов и нужно быстро из него выйти, не завершая при этом отладку.

Restart (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F5</kbd>) — Перезапустить отладку

Continue (<kbd>F5</kbd>) — Продолжает выполнения скрипта с текущего момента. Если больше нет других точек останова, то отладка заканчивается и скрипт продолжает работу. В ином случае работа прерывается на следующей точке останова.

Stop Debugging (<kbd>Shift+F5</kbd>) — Завершить отладку

...

Итак,  в текущем коде видно значение входного параметра:

- `data = "23 24 11 18"` —  строка с данными через пробел
- `numsStringArr = {"23", "24", "11", "18"}` — массив строк, который получился из входной переменной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажмем <kbd>F10</kbd> 2 раза, то окажемся на строке 11; во вкладках `Watch` и `Variables` и в самой странице с кодом увидим, что `nums` была инициализирована и в ней лежит массив целых чисел `{23, 24, 11, 18}` .

Если теперь нажмем <kbd>F10</kbd>, то попадем внутрь цикла `foreach` и нажимая теперь <kbd>F10</kbd> пока не окончится цикл, можно будет наблюдать на каждой итерации, как значение `num` и `sum` постоянно изменяются. `num` теперь можно будет наблюдать во вкладке `Watch`, потому что сейчас она доступна внутри цикла. Тем самым мы можем проследить шаг за шагом весь процесс изменения любых переменных и значений на любом этапе, который интересует.

Дальнейшие нажатия <kbd>F10</kbd> переместит линию кода на строки 15, 16 и, наконец, 20.

---

### **Дополнительно**

Если перейти во вкладку `Breakpoints` в нижней панели, то можно посмотреть все брейкпойнты, удалить все брейкпойнты, включить/выключить, а также еще более тонко настроить условие, при котором на данной отметке надо остановиться. В методе выше, например, нужно остановиться только когда `sum` превысит значение 20.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это удобно, если останов нужен только при определённом значении, а не всегда (особенно в случае с циклами).

Больше информации об отладке можно посмотреть в [Сведения об отладке кода C# с помощью Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).

Comment: "Это то место, где отладчик автоматически остановит выполнение **Java**" - внезапно =) опечатка полагаю, а в целом респект, мне никогда терпения не хватало расписать подробно работу с отладчиком.

Comment: У меня студия русская. Что делать? Ничего не понятно!

Comment: Интересно, почему под отладкой обычно подразумевают инструкцию вида "как перейти к следующей строке". И при этом забывают про основные принципы отладки - например то, что перед отладкой надо иметь строгое предположение - где и что идет не так. А не просто тыкать отладчиком наугдад :(

Comment: @PashaPash сарказм конечно, но все же: потому что длинную умную и невероятно скучную инструкцию пропустят мимо, так же как документацию. Читать долго, слова длинные и непонятные, лучше вопрос напишу, вдруг копипаста на халяву достанется. Как-то так. Из личного опыта работы со школьниками.

Comment: Было бы здорово добавить пару слов про отладку многопоточного кода. Хотя бы как открыть окно тредов/тасков и выбрать нужный поток/задачу. Потому что в уютном шарпике очень легко использовать таски и асинки, даже в книгах/статьях для начинающих об этом пишут. А как потом отлаживать?

Comment: Вот кстати "Вчера всё работало, а сегодня не работает" решается в первую очередь с помощью системы контроля версий (тот же `git bisect` из комментариев к вопросу).

Comment: @insolor можете дописать свой ответ. Хотя я бы его отнес скорее не сюда, а в общий топик  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701817/191482. Вообще это всё задумывалось для совсем новичков и те кто на руСО приходит с вопросом "у меня код не работает, чо делать" - отсылать их в такие ответы

Comment: Да, вполне хорошая ссылка что бы посылать новичков в.... отладчик)

Comment: traceback, print -ы.