# Почему в результате, цифры выше, чем оно есть?

Tags: c#

Только учусь.
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в результатах значения на 1 больше ?

[Можно посмотреть онлайн](https://repl.it/NWiP/0)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class CheckStrings
    {


        static void Main()
        {
            int VSEGO_SSILOK = 12;
            int KOLLICHESTVO_NOVIH_SSILOK = 0;
            int NACHALO_NOVIH_SSILOK = VSEGO_SSILOK - KOLLICHESTVO_NOVIH_SSILOK;

            string[,] spisok = new string[30, 15];
            List<string> SsilkiNew = new List<string>();

            SsilkiNew.Add("/1111"); // +
            SsilkiNew.Add("/5253"); // +
            SsilkiNew.Add("/2000");
            SsilkiNew.Add("/7000");
            SsilkiNew.Add("/17000"); // +
            SsilkiNew.Add("/5000");
            SsilkiNew.Add("/2500"); // +
            SsilkiNew.Add("/5555"); // +

            spisok[0, 0] = "/1000";
            spisok[1, 0] = "/2000";
            spisok[2, 0] = "/3000";
            spisok[3, 0] = "/4000";
            spisok[4, 0] = "/5000";
            spisok[5, 0] = "/6000";
            spisok[6, 0] = "/7000";
            spisok[7, 0] = "/8000";
            spisok[8, 0] = "/9000";
            spisok[9, 0] = "/10000";
            spisok[10, 0] = "/11000";
            spisok[11, 0] = "/12000";


            string[] spisokSsilok = new string[100];

            for (int i = 0; i < SsilkiNew.Count; i++)
            {
                string k = SsilkiNew[i].ToString();
                spisokSsilok[i] = k;

            }

            HashSet<string> checker = new HashSet<string>();
            for (int z = 0; z < VSEGO_SSILOK; ++z) checker.Add(spisok[z, 0]);

            foreach (string t in spisokSsilok)
            {
                if (!checker.Contains(t))
                {
                    spisok[VSEGO_SSILOK, 0] = t;
                    checker.Add(t);
                    VSEGO_SSILOK++;
                    KOLLICHESTVO_NOVIH_SSILOK++;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < spisok.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (spisok[i, 0] != null) {Console.WriteLine(spisok[i, 0]);}
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = NACHALO_NOVIH_SSILOK; i < spisok.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (spisok[i, 0] != null) { Console.WriteLine(spisok[i, 0]); }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.WriteLine("Всего в списке: " + VSEGO_SSILOK);
            Console.WriteLine("Новых ссылок: " + KOLLICHESTVO_NOVIH_SSILOK);
            Console.WriteLine("Начало новых: " + NACHALO_NOVIH_SSILOK);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте: комментарии в код, объяснение, что делает код, что выводит, что ожидаете в выводе, в чем конкретно проблема.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал посмотреть сюда: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/191482)  и не мучить с подобными вопросами никого вокруг никогда))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 2й день бьюсь головой и не понимаю почему счётчик, который должен показать что цикл прошёл 5 раз, показывает на 1 больше.

Comment: @Vipz почему ты считаешь что счетчик прошел 5 раз? И почему вместо того, чтобы биться головой ты просто не воспользуешься отладкой?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Объясняю быстро.

Но абсолютно точно рекомендую заглянуть в тему **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/191482)**, чтобы научиться самому разбираться  в коде на самом базовом уровне.

---

Т.к. `spisokSsilok` - это массив с длиной 100, то в строках:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SsilkiNew.Count; i++) {
    string k = SsilkiNew[i].ToString();
    spisokSsilok[i] = k;
}
```

ты заполняешь массив восемью элементами из `SsilkiNew` **и еще 92** у тебя заполняются пустыми строками.

В итоге вот здесь:

```
foreach (string t in spisokSsilok) {
    if (!checker.Contains(t))
```

Ты проверяешь не только значения `/1111`, `/5253` и т.д., но также еще проверяешь, что в списке `checker` нет элемента с пустой строчкой. Что является правдой. И это и является дополнительным элементов в множестве. Он добавляется, счётчики инкрементируются на лишнюю единицу.

Comment: Большое спасибо, пошагал и понял это, часть с foreach, можно сказать просто скопипастил не понимая как он работает, спасибо за ответ и статью. Буду обязательно пользоваться.