# Mассивы класса c шарп

Tags: c#, массивы

Не могу справится с, на первый взгляд,простой задачей: В строке найти количество  вхождений каждой буквы.Создал класс с двумя свойствами

```
class Struct1
{
    public  char Itsch { get; set; }
    public  int Itscon { get; set; } 
}
```

строку отсортировал перевел в  2 чаровских массива,в дном оставил только уникальные буквы и на его размере создал массив елементов класса

```
Struct1[] arr = new Struct1[size];
```

Теперь пытаюсь сделать так

```
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j <ch.Length -1; j++)
{
    arr[i] = new Struct();
    count = 1;  arr[i].Itsch = ch[j];
    while (ch[j] == ch[j + 1])
    {
        count++;
        j++;
    }
    arr[i].Itscon = сount;
    i++;
}
```

не получается! Пытаюсь выкрутиться двумя циклами

```
for (int i = 1; i < ch2.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new Struct1();
    arr[i].Itsch = ch2[i];
}
```

а затем

```
for(int j=0;j<ch.Length;j++)
{
    if (arr[j].Itsch == ch[j])
    arr[j].Itscon++;
}
```

Выбивает исключение `NullRefrences` во втором цикле, но как инициализировать `arr[j]`??? Если опять `arr[j] = new Struct1();` все обнулиться и `(arr[j].Itsch == ch[j])` станет бесполезна. Люди умные, помогите несчастному кто чем может!

Comment: Пожалуйста отформатируйте корректно код в вопросе

Comment: У вас первый цикл от единицы, а второй от нуля, отсюда и неиницилизированный элемент

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/218063) Еще один: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/218063)

Comment: @Андрей чисто технически, любой вопрос по любой ошибке в C# сводится к "Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?". Это не значит, что стоит закрывать любой вопрос по отладке как дубликат :) У топикастера цель - получить количество входжений каждой буквы. А не починить `NullRefrenceException`.

Answer (score 5):

С помощью Linq задача решается в одну строку:

```
string text = "qwertyuiodfghj9ij6ygrd3es7hiprrreeuuuqqqhhhhqqkkk";
var res = text.GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => new { Symbol = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
foreach (var r in res)
    Console.WriteLine("Количество символов {0} = {1}", r.Symbol, r.Count);
```

Группируем по символу и берем количество элементов в группе

Comment: Да верно , не уверен , что оппонент поймёт лямдавыражение, важно не решить задачу за оппонента, а дать понять принцип решения.

Comment: @DigitalCore, а регекспы поймет? Почему не просто `text.Count(c => c == letter)`?

Answer (score 1):

Идею решения вы уловили правильно, поэтому останавливаться на подробном алгоритме не стану. А вот реализовать эту идею можно многими способами, включая массу неэффективных во всех отношениях вариантов.

Никогда не торопитесь создавать новый класс. В BCL .NET для большинства распространенных задач все необходимое уже есть, нужно только потратить немного времени на чтение документации (или мастерски владеть Google-Fu =)) .

Если учесть, что от вас скорее всего хотят не однострочное решение, которое вы вряд ли сможете объяснить, то стоило обратить внимание на класс [**Dictionary**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Тогда подсчет количества одинаковых букв будет выглядеть так:

```
var inputString = "hghjkgdjfbdgfjafsdjagfuieruisdcjbvhuidh";
var result = new Dictonary<char, int>();
foreach(var c in inputString)
{
    if(result.ContainsKey(c))
        result[c]++;
    else
        result.Add(c, 1);
}
foreach(var c in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{c.Key} = {c.Value}");
}
```

Это хороший вариант, достаточно быстрый, но очень вероятно, что от вас хотят увидеть не это, т.к. я хорошо знаком со спецификой обучения информатике в наших школах.

Тогда можно использовать решение совсем "в лоб", которое, к тому же, будет еще и на порядок быстрее любых LiNQ, Dictionary и тем более RegExp-ов.

Вспоминаем, что `char` - это на самом деле `int`, в том смысле, что символы хранятся в виде их числовых кодов. Скорее всего, в вашей задаче есть ограничение на диапазон символов, но для простоты, возьмем все символы двухбайтового unicode, который используется в .NET

```
//Для 2х-байтового юникода это всего 2^16 возможных символов.
//Элементы массива по умолчанию инициализируются 0, в отличие от C/C++.
int[] counters = new int[65536];
var inputString = "hghjkgdjfbdgfjafsdjagfuieruisdcjbvhuidh";
for(int i = 0; i < inputString.Count(); i++)
{
    counters[(int)inputString[i]]++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
{
    if(counters[i] > 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"{(char)i} = {counters[i]}");
}
```

Главная идея заключается в том, что у элемента массива уже есть два независимых значения: индекс элемента и его содержимое. На Паскале это выглядит более очевидно, т.к. в качестве индексов можно использовать символы. В Си-подобных языках индекс всегда число, поэтому нужно предварительно преобразовать `char` в `int`, а потом уже использовать его в качестве индекса.

Да, тут есть избыточность по используемой памяти, но она компенсируется скоростью доступа по индексу к массиву и отсутствием создания дополнительных объектов "за кадром", как в случае с LiNQ и RegExp. К тому же, набор входных символов, скорее всего, будет ограничен набором однобайтовых символов, в этом случае можно обрезать длину массива до 256, или ASCII-символов, в этом случае можно обрезать длину массива до 128. Также можно вычесть первые 32 непечатных символа, только не забудьте, что вычитать их нужно при каждом преобразовании char в int, т.к. индексация массива всегда начинается с 0.

Красивое короткое решение уже написал [@Андрей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/749378/198316), будет замечательно, если вы разберетесь как оно работает, только не вздумайте писать такое решение на ЕГЭ, проверяющие не поймут, а вам придется таскаться по апелляциям.

Answer (score 0):

Всё на много проще, чем кажется на первый взгляд. Используем Linq, и RegularExpressions.

```csharp
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string text = "qwertyuiodfghj9ij6ygrd3es7hiprrreeuuuqqqhhhhqqkkk";
            foreach (var letter in text.Distinct().ToArray())
            {
                var count = Regex.Matches(text, letter.ToString()).Count;
                Console.WriteLine("Количество символов {0} = {1}", letter, count);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О_о, и регэкспы приплели сюда?

Comment: Ну, эээ. Это, конечно, решение, но оно пробегает строку столько раз, сколько в ней различных букв.

Comment: Да согласен, но я привёл пример в качестве обучения ,  не решение за оппонента, лямда - разворачивается тоже в немалую конструкцию.

Comment: @DigitalCore в качестве обучения чему? Как не надо делать? Это будет даже покруче чем конкатенация string-ов в цикле, которая встречается в каждом втором "типа учебнике" или самоучителе.

Comment: `ToArray` не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Думаю в конкретно вашем случае решить можно проще. Хорошо, что вы отсортировали строку, но зачем после этого включать дополнительный цикл внутрь. Не проще ли первый элемент создать перед циклом, а не делать это внутри. И после каждый последующий символ сравнивать с текущим в вашем результирующем массиве.

```
int i = 0;
arr[i] = new Struct() { Itsch = ch[0], Itscon = 1 };

for (int j = 1; j <ch.Length; j++)
{
    if (arr[i].Itsch == ch[j])
        arr[i].Itscon++;
    else
    {
        i++;
        arr[i] = new Struct() { Itsch = ch[j], Itscon = 1 };
    }
}
```

Это решение только для конкретно вашего инструментария. Использование лямбд, как показали выше, действительно упростит решение.