# Почему в treeView ничего не выводит? - C#

Tags: c#

Вот есть такой код вывода данных из БД в treeView:

```
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM s_categories ORDER BY parent_id ASC", connect))
        {
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var nodes = new Dictionary<int, TreeNode>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    int id = dr.GetInt32(0);
                    int? parentId = dr.IsDBNull(1) ? null : (int?)dr.GetInt32(1);
                    string name = dr.GetString(2);

                    var node = new TreeNode(name);
                    TreeNode parent;
                    if (parentId == null)
                        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node); // Добавление ноды в контрол TreeView
                    else if (nodes.TryGetValue(parentId.Value, out parent))
                        parent.Nodes.Add(node);
                    nodes.Add(id, node);
                }
            }
        }
```

При запуске программы в treeView ничего не выводится, хотя ошибок никаких не пишет, в чем проблема?

Comment: Проверьте под отладчиком, строчка `treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);` хоть раз выполняется

Comment: @АндрейNOP , извините, а как это сделать в Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Почитайте это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/218063

Comment: @АндрейNO, спасибо, даже нашел ошибку. В строке `if (parentId == null)` у меня приходит с БД 0, а не null.

Comment: Ну и отлично, приходите еще.