# DateTimePicker при клике на дату вывести сообщение

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно что бы при выборе конкретной даты через if выводилось сообщение,
например если выбрано 2018, 12, 19 вывести слово Holiday

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(1985, 6, 20);
        dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;

        //if (dateTimePicker1.Value = 2018 , 12, 18)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Holliday");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Ну и какой тип у `dateTimePicker1.Value`? Правильно, `DateTime`. С чем мы сравниваем значения? С объектом того же типа. Как идет сравнение? Двумя знаками равно (`==`). Исходя из этого к какому выводу приходим?

Comment: EvgeniyZ   if (dateTimePicker1.Value == new DateTime(2018 , 12, 18)) верно?

Comment: А что мешает проверить?) Ведь не будете же вы при каждом "чихе" спрашивать помощи у прохожих. Попробуйте, нечего плохого не случится!

Comment: Компилируется нормально но не появляется MessageBox при выборе этой даты

Comment: Следующий шаг - отладка. Поставьте [точку остановки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701431/220553) на строку if  и посмотрите чему равен Value, равен ли он той дате, что вы указали? Скажу сразу, скорей всего нет, ибо вы выбираете число 18, когда ограничиваете диапазон дат текущим (16) и из за этого после строки `dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;` контрол не воспримет дату выше текущей, выбирая заместо нее последнее доступное (16). Кстати, такое ограничение в событие нет смысла делать, достаточно в конструкторе прописать, либо один раз при инициализации формы (например).

Comment: Все заработало , спасибо

Comment: Полученный вариант с вашими комментариями (только поподробнее, будущим читателям должно быть понятно) можете оформить как ответ. "Закроем" таким образом вопрос.