# Вопрос по циклам в C#

Tags: c#

```
int j = 2;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i = i + 2)
{
    j = j - 1;
    while(j < 15) 
    { 
        j = j + 5;
    }
}
```

Сколько раз в этом цикле будет выполняться строка j = j - 1;
Почему цикл выполниться 50 раз? Обьясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну вы считаете от 1 до 99 через два, то есть 1,3,5....99. Сколько раз посчитаете?

Comment: @tym32167, 49? :-)

Answer (score 4):

С помощью отладчика и точек остановки вы сможете понять как работает тот или иной код, а также найти ошибки.
[image: пример использования точки остановки]

Comment: Чудесный пример хорошего ответа, который не отвечает на поставленный вопрос. Но при этом остается хорошим ответом который учит больше чем "прямой ответ" :) От меня плюс.

Comment: @Andrew спасибо за положительную оценку.

Comment: Солидарен с **Andrew** :D Тоже плюс)

Comment: Возможный дубликат ответа: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/218063)

Answer (score 1):

Работа цикла такова (грубо):

1. Если условие (здесь `i < 100`) `false`, то покидаем цикл
2. Выполнить код внутри цикла
3. Выполнить действие цикла (здесь `i = i + 2`)

### Почему цикл работает 50 раз?

Все очень просто: сперва `i = 0`, после 1-й итерации `i = 2` (увеличивается на `2`), после 2-й итерации `i = 4` и т. д. После n-й итерации `i = n * 2`. Цикл завершается, когда `i >= 100`, а после 50 итераций `i = 100` (`i = 50 * 2 = 100`). Вот и получается эти 50 раз, т. к. Вы увеличили скорость "роста" `i` в 2 раза.

### Сколько раз выполнится `j = j - 1`

Столько раз сколько и цикл выполнит итераций, т. е. 50 раз.

Comment: Только там i=1 :D

Comment: @Kamushek я не заметил :D