# Асинхронное заполнение ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Стоит задача : при инициализации выполняется заполнение `ObservableCollection` данными, где имеется трудоемкий метод.

```
private void AddToCollection()
{
  Music.Add(new SongModel
  {
      Title = Tag.Title ,
      Artis = Tag.Artist
      ShadowColor = au.GetShadowColor(bm),       
   });
}
```

где **au.GetShadowColor(bm)** метод который долго обрабатывается.

Вызываю его в

```
 public PageViewModel()
 {   
   AddToCollection();
 }
```

Пытаясь найти решение понял что данный метод лучше не вызывать в конструкторе. **Тогда как и где его вызвать?**
Дальше вопрос как заполнять `ObservableCollection` так, чтобы не блокировать Ui и не ждать пока закончится заполнение чтобы отобразить окно программы?

**UPDATE:**
Действительно была проблема в GetShadowColor. Поля нужно инициализировать именно в самом методе, а не в классе. Так как иначе при вызове метода несколько раз асинхронно, методы будут обращаться одновременно к одним и тем же полям, что впоследствии создает исключения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так:

```
private async Task AddToCollection()
{
    Music.Add(new SongModel
    {
      Title = Tag.Title ,
      Artis = Tag.Artist
      ShadowColor = await Task.Run(()=> au.GetShadowColor(bm)),       
   });
}
```

Comment: var sc = await Task.Run(() => au.GetShadowColor(bm)); Появляется ошибка "ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта"

Comment: где появляется, что именно у вас равно null?

Comment: скорее всего sc=null. Ошибка выскакивает при инициализации программы при присваивание значения для DataContext

Comment: это может быть тольео ксли вот это `au.GetShadowColor(bm)` вернуло null

Comment: Да так как на половине выполнения метода вылетает эта ошибка, соответственно до  return не доходит

Comment: ну вам наверное надо глядеть внутрь метода `GetShadowColor`, и [пользоваться дебагером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701431/179763).