# Почему не работает конструкция if после выполнения условия?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Буду краток: игрок подходит к еде и, при нажатии на E, пополняет полоску голода.
Проблема кроется где-то в моменте нажатия кнопки E, так как без этой части кода всё прекрасно работает. Если переменную bool, отвечающую за нажатие E, сделать публичной, то видно, что само нажатие срабатывает, но код, что идёт в дальнейшем, почему-то нет.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        if(coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Properties_food>() != null) //проверка на то, есть ли у объекта нужный скрипт
        {
            dataFood = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Properties_food>();
            if(isE == true) //проверка bool, отвечающая за нажатие кнопки
            {
                if(dataFood.kind == "fruit")
                {
                    attribute.hunger += dataFood.satiety;
                    dataFood.bulk -= 5.0f;
                }

                if(dataFood.kind == "meat" || dataFood.kind == "fish")
                {
                    attribute.poisoning += dataFood.satiety;
                    dataFood.bulk -= 5.0f;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: В представленном клочке кода судя по всему указан обработчик, выполняющийся при обнаружении пересечения с объектом. Соответственно условие `if(isE == true)` видимо может сработать только если кнопка уже нажата при подходе.

Comment: [Отладка кода для начинающих](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2019). Так как ваш код не содержит явной ошибки, на ваш вопрос не возможно дать объективный ответ, только гипотезы.

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Comment: OnCollisionEnter OnCollisionStay OnCollisionExit... чувствуешь разницу?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возможно вам следует использовать OnCollisionStay, т.к. OnClollisionEnter выполняется раз, когда в него входят.

Т.е.:

1) Игрок входит OnCollisionEnter

2) OnCollisionEnter срабатывает, но видит, что кнопка не нажата (false)

3) Игрок нажимает E и срабатывает True

4) Ничего, т.к. OnCollisionEnter сработал лишь один раз и он не повторяется

P.s. Я бы лучше использовал OnTriggerStay2D, а также вместо `if(isE == true)` написал бы

```
Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.E)
{
     // код...
}
```

Т.е. пока игрок находится в триггере, то он может нажать E и съесть еду

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Однако, всё равно не работает по какой-то причине. Пробовал и Button, и Input - ничего

Comment: Попробуй вместо OnCollisionEnter использовать OnTriggerStay. 

1) Поставь Collider на тот объект, к которому должен подойти игрок, расширь его (чтобы весь спрайт игрока мог влезть в него + немного места на всякий случай), а также поставь галочку isTrigger

2) Добавь RigidBody и убери с него галочку Use gravity

3) Используй свой скрипт, но смени на `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2d coll)`

Должно сработать
@МаксЮ

Comment: @МаксЮ Я попробую записать видео и показать

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score -1):

Показал полностью в видео как можно решить проблему. Правда я показал в 3d, а не в 2d, но думаю не будет это столь значимым, т.к. принцип один и тот же.

https://youtu.be/nsvGeTVVEnA