# Имя переменной, переданное в аргументе C#

Tags: c#

Проблема такая - когда дебажишь что-то с помощью Console.WriteLine, хочется просто и быстро узнать значения всех аргументов. Думал сделать так

```
void Main()
{
int i = 5;
string g = "test";

MassConsoleWriteLine(i,j);
}

void MassConsoleWriteLine(object[] params)
{
string s = "";
foreach(var k in params)
{
s+= nameof(k) + " is " + k + ", ";
}
Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
i is 5, g is test
```

Оно не работает - в случае foreach nameof выдает имя внутренней переменной цикла, т.е. k, а в случае for код не компилируется, ибо params[index] не имеет имени.

Как сделать чтобы работало? Я понимаю что они различаются типом - string ссылочный, int значения, однако задача именно сделать универсальный метод - пусть ест любые типа и если может - выводит их значения.

Comment: Не уверен, что есть нормальный механизм, кроме передавать туда прямо `nameof` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363753/get-instance-name-c-sharp

Comment: пользуйтесь [отладкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701431/179763), не изобретайте колесо.

Comment: Показанный код не компилируется.

Comment: @aepot о чем я в начале и написал в посте - 
`Оно не работает - в случае foreach nameof выдает имя внутренней переменной цикла, т.е. k, а в случае for код не компилируется, ибо params[index] не имеет имени.`

Comment: @aepot Да, я таким тоже страдал, это нужно что бы "дамп" сделать с локальными переменными. Ваш пример, для "частного" случая, и если "подложены" исходники. Ответ - такое можно сделать через анализ IL-кода (тогда отпадает проблема с исходниками, но много мороки с IL). Если не приложен pdb-файл - то можно получить "номера" локальных переменных, которые переданы в ф-цию. Есми приложен - то из pdb файла можно узнать имена локальных переменных. Если есть и pdb и исходники - то можно и таким способом, миинуя IL.

Comment: @nick_n_a комментарий не туда попал?)

Comment: @aepot я думаю нет смысла оспаривать ответ, т.к. лучше я за короткое время ненапишу. Возможно у кого-то валяется решение через IL, но маловероятно.

Comment: @nick_n_a это не рабочее решение, а учебный пример. К тому же весьма специфичный. Я ответ написал просто, потому что знаю как добиться желаемого автором результата. На пуленепробиваемость этот код даже близко не претендует. Более того, очевидео, что без наличия исходников он даже работать не будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще это странное занятие, то что вы делаете. Есть отладчик, он вам всё покажет. Но если очень хочется, то почему бы и нет. Хотя-бы для развлечения.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 5;
        string j = "test";

        MassConsoleWriteLine(i, j);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void MassConsoleWriteLine(params object[] parameters)
    {
        // берем стек вызовов и фрейм номер 1 из него, это будет как раз вызывающая строка кода
        StackFrame frame = new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(1);
        // достаем текст этой строки из файла с C# кодом
        string codeLine = File.ReadAllLines(frame.GetFileName())[frame.GetFileLineNumber() - 1].Trim();
        // достаем имена переменных из строки кода
        // я не силен в регулярках, возможно можно сделать красивее
        string[] vars = Regex.Match(codeLine, @"\((.+?)\)").Groups[1].Value.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

        // формируем вывод
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            output.Add($"{vars[i]} is {parameters[i]}");
        }

        // выводим
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", output));
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
i is 5, j is test
```

Здесь много условностей и ограничений, и при изменении условий использования этого кода потребуются доработки. Но на вашем примере оно работает исправно.

Comment: Как-то так должно быть поуниверсальнее: `MassConsoleWriteLine\((?:(\w+),?)*\)` потом `Groups[1].Captures`, правда, с методами по-прежнему не работает. Ну и в случае 2 и более вызовов в одной строке тоже получится фигня.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну я не претендую на анализатор кода. :) Если попытаться учесть все варианты, можно написать C# парсер, то есть тот самый велосипед. Поэтому ограничусь примитивным решением.

Comment: Я считал, моё тоже довольно примитивное)))

Comment: @Qwertiy не могу заставить работать паттерн из вашего первого комментария. Ни в коде, не на regex101.

Comment: Я про пробелы забыл. Вот, так мэтчится: `MassConsoleWriteLine\s*\(\s*(?:(\w+)\s*,?\s*)*\)`