# Ошибка: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (selected_response == correct_answers_number) correct_answers =
                                       correct_answers + 1;
    if (selected_response != correct_answers_number)
    {
        wrong_answers = wrong_answers + 1;

        array[wrong_answers] = label1.Text;
    }
    if (button1.Text == "Начать тестирование сначала")
    {
        button1.Text = "Следующий вопрос";

        radioButton1.Visible = true;
        radioButton2.Visible = true;
        radioButton3.Visible = true;
        
        start(); return;

    }
    if (button1.Text == "Завершить")
    {

        Read.Close();

        radioButton1.Visible = false;
        radioButton2.Visible = false;
        radioButton3.Visible = false;

        label1.Text = String.Format("Тестирование завершино.\n" +
            "Правельных ответов:{0} из {1}.\n" +
            "Набранные баллы: {2:F2}.", correct_answers,
            quection_count, (correct_answers * 5.0F) / quection_count);

        button1.Text = "Начать тестирование сначала";

        var Str = "Список ошибок" +
            ":\n\n";
        for (int i = 1; i <= wrong_answers; i++)
            Str = Str + array[i] + "\n";


        if(wrong_answers != 0) MessageBox.Show(
                                 Str, "Тестирование завершино");
        
        if (button1.Text == "Следующий вопрос") вопрос();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где у вас описание `array`, какого он размера вообще?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите какой длины у вас `array`. Потом посмотрите какое число у вас выдаёт `wrong_answers` при ошибке. Сопоставьте эти два факта)) Оцените, есть ли у вас в массиве такой индекс, который выдаёт `wrong_answers`

А чтобы можно было посмотреть информацию в процессе - вот вам в помощь: **[C# - Debugging (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701431/191482)**

и ещё информация по отладке с оф. сайта: **[Microsoft - Учебник. Сведения об отладке кода C# с помощью Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019)**

Comment: Еще [полезная ссылка про отладку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @aepot спасибо. добавил в ответ

Comment: Минус мой, ответ бесполезен и избыточен, для того чтобы дать ссылку на ответ, в котором есть вся необходимая информация к вопросу необходимо пользоваться штатным функционалом дубликатов, а не копировать ссылку в новый ответ. Если у вас если дополнительная информация к ответу, который расположен по ссылке, то необходимо добавить ее там