# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Taks.Start () (at Assets/Scripts 2/Taks.cs:27)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю простую игру викторину. И использую готовый текст и просто делю его с помощью Split.
И у меня все прекрасно работает но выдаёт вот такую ошибку NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. И из-за этой ошибки не получается скомпилировать её.
Вот тут выдаёт ошибку

```
string[] A = Answers.Split(';');
```

И ее выдаёт вроде на всех переменных которые связанны с этой

А вот весь код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Taks : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset All;
    string Text;
    public string TasK;
    public string Answers;
    public Text Tesk;
    public Text a1;
    public Text a2;
    public Text a3;
    public Text a4;
    public string True;

    void Start()
    {
        Text = All.text;
        string[] s = Text.Split('/');
        TasK = s[0];
        Answers = s[1];
        True = s[2];
        Tesk.text = TasK;
        string[] A = Answers.Split(';');
        a1.text = A[0];
        a2.text = A[1];
        a3.text = A[2];
        a4.text = A[3];
    }


    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Я ещё только начинаю.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: [Debugging (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701431/191482)...... в вашем случае надо  прикрутить отладку у юнити. И смотреть что на каждой строчке происходит... в частности что хранится в `Answers`

Comment: Answers у меня хранит варианты ответов и это можно посмотреть в юнити

Comment: из-за чего возникает данная ошибка?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-nullreferenceexception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: _из-за чего возникает данная ошибка?_ Если в строчке `Answers.Split`, то из-за того что `Answers` = `null`. Кстати, _И у меня все прекрасно работает но выдаёт вот такую ошибку_ звучит как фраза, противоречащая сама себе.

Comment: я знаю и по этому не понимаю почему выдаёт такую ошибку. В юнити можно увидеть что Answers не пуста.

Comment: @МаксимилианАляшев если не пуста - то зависит от того, что в ней. А может и не на эту строку ругается вовсе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хм, а данная ошибка может помешать компиляции? Или ей мешают все ошибки?

Comment: @МаксимилианАляшев компиляция не происходит пока не будут устранены все ошибки (уровня error)