# Вывести на экран данные

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, консоль

Подскажите насчет следующего. Есть 2 класса - Model:

```
class Model
{
    List<string> SecID = new List<string>();

    StreamReader txtsecid = new StreamReader("Secid.txt");

    string xmlName = /* ссылка на xml файл, находящийся на сайте */
    string xpathName = "//document//data//rows//row[@SECID='"; // Запрос XPath


    string xmlPrice = /* ссылка на xml файл, находящийся на сайте */
    string xpathPrice = "//document//data//rows//row[@SECID='"; // Запрос XPath
    string test = "";

    public void GetDataFromXml(Share share)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(xmlName);
        XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        
        XmlNodeList childnodes = xRoot.SelectNodes(xpathName);
        foreach (XmlNode n in childnodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.InnerText);

        }
        

    }

    public Model()
    {
        while (!txtsecid.EndOfStream)
        {
            SecID.Add(txtsecid.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SecID.Count; i++)
        {
            Share share = new Share(SecID[i], xmlName + ", " + (xpathName + SecID[i] + "']/@SECNAME"), xmlPrice + ", " + (xpathPrice + SecID[i] + "']/@PREVADMITTEDQUOTE"));
            GetDataFromXml(share);
        }
    }


}
```

Share:

```
class Share
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecID { get; set; }

    public Share(string SecID, string Name, string Price)
    {
        this.SecID = SecID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Price = Price;
    }

    

}
```

Немного опишу код. В файле Secid.txt находятся 260 наименований построчно. С помощью них можно получить данные о конкретном объекте, который находиться в файлах xmlName и xmlPrice, где я описал в цикле
Подскажите, как мне вывести на консоль/занести в класс данные из XML файлов и что я сделал неправильно и глупо. Через WEBSERVICE/IMPORTXML в Excel и Google Таблицах соответственно все получалось. Заранее спасибо

Comment: то есть где то есть какой то XML файл (а то и два), у него какая то стрктура внутри, а ещё есть текстовый файл, и у него что то внутри, но вы нам ничего этого не покажете, то зато покажете код, который не ясно работает ли вообще, так как вы не можете результат этого кода куда либо вывести и не умеете отладчиком пользоваться, я верно понял?

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Comment: Зачем метка WPF? Ваш вопрос хоть как-то с ней связан?

Comment: Название вашего вопроса совершенно не соответствует его сути. Если вы не знаете, как **распарсить** xml, так и спросите. Почему вы пишете про вывод на экран? Не знаете, как пользоваться WriteLine? Отредактируйте вопрос.