# System.StackOverflowException при создании объекта формы С#

Tags: c#, исключения

Есть две формы, один класс. С основной формы открываю вторую:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            form2.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
```

В дополнительном классе я так же создаю объект на вторую форму

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
```

И вот на эту строку выдаёт исключение System.StackOverflowException. Больше я нигде не создаю объект на вторую форму. Как можно обойти эту проблемку? Ведь мне нужно через методы этого класса изменять компоненты на второй форме.
Вот весь код:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            form2.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
    }

public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Ans ans = new Ans();
        private int index = -1;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ans.Test(radioButton1, radioButton2);

            Shown += Form1_Shown15;
        }

        private void radioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton button = sender as RadioButton;

            if (button == radioButton1) { index = 0; }
            if (button == radioButton2) { index = 1; }
        }

        private async void Form1_Shown25(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            verticalProgressBar1.Value = 100;
            for (int i = 25 * 60; i > 0; i--)
            {
                verticalProgressBar1.Value = i * 100 / (25 * 60);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ans.Correct(index);

                radioButton1.Checked = false;
                radioButton2.Checked = false;

                index = -1;
            }
            catch { return; }

            ans.Index++;

            if (ans.Index > 47)
            {
                MessageBox.Show();
                return;
            }
            ans.Test(radioButton1, radioButton2);
        }
    }
public class Ans
{
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();

        private List<string> test = new List<string>()
        { };

        private bool[,] boolTest =
        { };

        public int correct = 0;

        public int TestIndex { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }

        public string GetCorrect { get; set; }

        public void Test(Control control1, Control control2)
        {
            control1.Text = test[TestIndex];
            TestIndex++;
            control2.Text = test[TestIndex];
            TestIndex++;
        }

        public void Correct(int i)
        {
            SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
            #region 1-10
            //1
            if (Index == 0)
            {
                if (boolTest[0, i] == true)
                {
                    form2.pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    form2.label2.Text = "";
                    correct++;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    form2.pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    form2.label2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: У вас где-то рекурсия, воспользуйтесь отладчиком

Comment: Не умею им пользоваться.

Comment: В таком случае самое время научиться: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/218063 без отладки нет разработки

Comment: Ошибка за пределами показанного кода. Показывайте методы целиком. И зачем вам несколько копий `Form2`?

Comment: @aepot Вот, добавил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь всё просто, при создании `Form2` происходит

```
Ans ans = new Ans(); // создание новой копии объекта на основе класса Ans
```

А при создании класса `Ans` просходит

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // создание новой копии Form2
```

А при создании `Form2` происходит

```
Ans ans = new Ans(); // создание новой копии объекта на основе класса Ans.
```

А при создании класса `Ans` просходит

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // создание новой копии Form2
```

А при создании `Form2` происходит

```
Ans ans = new Ans(); // создание новой копии объекта на основе класса Ans
```

А при создании класса `Ans` просходит

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // создание новой копии Form2
```

А при создании `Form2` происходит

```
Ans ans = new Ans(); // создание новой копии объекта на основе класса Ans
```

А при создании класса `Ans` просходит

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // создание новой копии Form2
```

А при создании `Form2` происходит

```
Ans ans = new Ans(); // создание новой копии объекта на основе класса Ans
```

А при создании класса `Ans` просходит

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // создание новой копии Form2
```

А при создании `Form2` происходит

```
Ans ans = new Ans(); // создание новой копии объекта на основе класса Ans
```

А при создании класса `Ans` просходит

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // создание новой копии Form2
```

А при создании `Form2` происходит

```
Ans ans = new Ans(); // создание новой копии объекта на основе класса Ans
```

А при создании класса `Ans` просходит

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // создание новой копии Form2
```

...и так далее

---

И каждый такой вызов помещает точку возврата в стек. Стек хранит место, куда возвращаться, ведь когда вы пишете `return` или метод заканчивается, процессор достает из того самого стека указатель, куда возращаться.

А у вас  вызов в вызове в вызове и т.д.. И всё это попадает в стек. Но у стека есть размер, обычно это 1 мегабайт. Так как вы вечно продолжаете туда добавлять точки возрата (бесконечная рекурсия), стек переполняется, и вы получаете `StackOverflowException`.

Типичный пример бесконечной рекурсии

```cs
void MyMethod()
{
    MyMethod();
}
```

А ваш случай выглядит вот так

```cs
void MyMethod1()
{
    MyMethod2();
}

void MyMethod2()
{
    MyMethod1();
}
```

Не создавайте новую форму в классе `Ans`, используйте существующую.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Ans ans;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ans = new Ans(this);
        ans.Test(radioButton1, radioButton2);

        Shown += Form1_Shown15;
    }
}

public class Ans
{
    Form2 form2;

    public Ans(Form2 f2)
    {
        form2 = f2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, Вы часто меня выручаете!

Comment: @ЯрославОвчар разберите этот ответ и все примеры в нём. Что, почему и как работает. Еще пересаньте писать свой код в конструкторе формы, вместо этого используйте обработчик события `Form.Load`.

Comment: На примере всё ясно, советам последую, ещё раз спасибо)

Comment: Шикарный ответ: и по делу и с юмором!