# Не меняется текст на кнопке Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, switch

Есть предположения почему?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MenuButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Назначить вручную")]
    public Text mainButton; //Ссылка на главную кнопку
    
    public void OnClick() {
        switch (mainButton.text) { //Переключатель который меняет текст на кнопке при нажатии
            case "Выбрать уровень":
                mainButton.text = "Назад";
                break;
            case "Назад":
                mainButton.text = "Выбрать уровень";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте в отладчике посмотреть, поставьте breakpoint на `switch`. Попадает ли вообще туда управление? Если попадает, то что в этот момент в `mainButton.text` и как отрабатывает `switch`?

Comment: @CrazyElf Если я вас правильно понял, то не попадает

Comment: значит вывод: клик не работает)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Клик работает, проверил с помощью Debug.Log, но вот сам switch не работает

Comment: Если доходит до `switch`, то посмотрите, что в `mainButton.text` в этот момент. А вообще я так и не понял - попадает в `OnClick` или нет.

Comment: @DonutTheory значит текст различается. А в целом `Debug.Log`  и отладка - это не одно и то же. (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/191482)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Хорошо, а что тогда с кодом делать? можно ли как то вручную назначить одно из состояний switch кнопке?

Comment: @DonutTheory имеется в виду по-умолчанию? Ну да, идетё в инспектор, открываете компонент, находите свойство текст и ставите значение.. Либо при загрузке сцены в методе Awake или Start находите компонент и ставите текст

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ни в какую не работает, это даже не switch, не могу просто текст сменить через код, сейчас попробую по другому код переписать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Заработало, сам не знаю что я сделал, вроде скрипт присоединил к самой кнопке, в любом случае спасибо за попытки помочь