# Удаление случайной строки и столбца двухмерного массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Программа должна удалять рандомную строку и столбец и выводить новый массив, но возникает ошибка - не могу отловить почему

```
using System;
class T9
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[,] nums = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
        Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив:");
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(nums[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int row = rnd.Next(nums.GetLength(0));
        int col = rnd.Next(nums.GetLength(1));
        Console.WriteLine("Удаляется {0}-я строка и {1}-й столбец", row, col);
        int[,] NewNums = new int[nums.GetLength(0)-1, nums.GetLength(0)-1];
        int a, b;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (i < row) a = i;
            else a = i - 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (j < col) b = j; 
                else b = j - 1;
                NewNums[a, b] = nums[i, j];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Новый массив:");
        for (int i = 0; i < NewNums.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < NewNums.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(NewNums[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: в чём состоит ошибка, должны именно вы сказать. ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неверно построена логика удаления, но начну не с этого. Первое, что нужно сделать, чтобы не путаться в коде - это начать писать методы. Например метод вывод матрицы на экран.

```cs
private static void ShowArray(int[,] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[i, j] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Теперь в основном коде можно будет избежать повторения одного и того же дважды. Проще код - виднее ошибки, когда они есть. Чаще используйте вынос кода в методы.

Теперь о вашей основной ошибке. Дело в том, что цикл, который занимается удалением строки и столбца у вас выполняется на 1 раз больше по вертикали и горизонтали, чем нужно, потому что вы его запускаете по размерам исходной матрицы, а не результирующей. Все что нужно сделать - это перевернуть логику итерируясь по результирующей матрице и добавлять единицу индексатору, а не вычитать.

```cs
private static int[,] DeleteCross(int[,] array, int row, int col)
{
    int[,] result = new int[array.GetLength(0) - 1, array.GetLength(1) - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        int a = i >= row ? i + 1 : i;
        for (int j = 0; j < result.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            int b = j >= col ? j + 1 : j;
            result[i, j] = array[a, b];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Надеюсь, вы знакомы с тернарным оператором, если нет, то это краткая запись обычного `if-else` - [почитать можно здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

Итоговый код выглядит так.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] nums = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
    Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив:");
    ShowArray(nums);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int row = rnd.Next(nums.GetLength(0));
    int col = rnd.Next(nums.GetLength(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Удаляется {0}-я строка и {1}-й столбец", row, col);
    int[,] result = DeleteCross(nums, row, col);
    Console.WriteLine("Новый массив:");
    ShowArray(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Обратите внимание, насколько проще и понятнее стал выглядеть основной код.

Вывод в консоль.

```
Исходный массив:
1 2 3
4 5 6
Удаляется 1-я строка и 1-й столбец
Новый массив:
1 3
```

Кстати, пользователю вы выводите не порядковый номер строки и столбца, а их индексы. Несмотря на то что вывод верный, люди все-таки считают строки и столбцы начиная с единицы, а не с нуля. Так что можно добавить единичку индексам, чтобы вывод был более дружелюбным человеку.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка здесь:

```
int[,] NewNums = new int[nums.GetLength(0)-1, nums.GetLength(0)-1];
```

Второй размер должен быть от GetLength(1) а не от 0:

```
int[,] NewNums = new int[nums.GetLength(0)-1, nums.GetLength(1)-1];
```

Comment: Да, но это не единственная ошибка :)