# "Индекс находился вне границ массива." c#

Tags: c#, массивы

```
using System;

namespace _7лаб
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const int n = 3;
            string[][] ch = new string[n][]
            {
                new string [] {"один", "два", "три"},
                new string [] {"четыре", "пять"},
                new string [] {"шесть", "семь", "восемь", "девять"}
            };
            for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ch.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{ch[i][j],6}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Строка `Console.Write($"{ch[i][j],6}");` вызывает исключение. В чем проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: Предлагаю вам самостоятельно отдебажить и понять проблему ↑↑↑

Comment: Проблема в том, что массиве `ch` - три элемента, а в массиве `ch[1]` - два.

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < x[i].Length; j++)
                    Console.Write($"{x[i][j],9}");
я все исправила, спасибо большое

Comment: @АделzИдрисова Молодец. Можете написать ответ и принять его.

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, надо поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка:

> Индекс вне границ массива

возникает из за того, что во 2-м цикле вы используете длину многомерного массива, а не длину подмассива:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ch[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{ch[i][j],6}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```