# Я не понимаю работу конструкции (Далее в вопросе)

Tags: c#, сортировка

**(Добрый день форумчане. Прошу вашей помощи)**

В одной книге по C# был работающий,непонятный мне код

```
public static void Main()
{
    int c = 0;
    int[] bv = { 4, 2, 2, 4, 57, 73521, 32 };
    for(int i = 1;i<bv.Length;i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < bv.Length-i; j++) {
            if (bv[j] > bv[j + 1])
            {
                c = bv[j + 1];
                bv[j + 1] = bv[j];
                bv[j] = c;

            }

        }
    
    for (int k = 0; k < bv.Length; k++)
    {
        Console.Write(bv[k].ToString() + " ");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Я не понимаю почему вот эта часть

```
for(int i = 1;i<bv.Length;i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < bv.Length-i; j++) {
            if (bv[j] > bv[j + 1])
            {
                c = bv[j + 1];
                bv[j + 1] = bv[j];
                bv[j] = c;

            }

        }
```

работает 5 раз ведь по теории должна всего 4

Прошу вашей помощи взамен на "Good vibes"

Comment: А мы не понимаем что Вы пытаетесь спросить.

Comment: Извините за некорректный вопрос, очень жаль.

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Шаг 1: Ставишь точку останова (кликаешь слева напротив нужной строчки кода).

Шаг 2: Проверяешь значения переменных (просто наведи курсор на переменную)

Шаг 3: Пошагово наблюдаешь за изменением состояния переменных (жми F11)

Шаг 4: ???

Шаг 5: PROFIT !

Comment: Благодарю! Sending you good vibes. P.s.(спасибо, я как раз не понимал что это за штука)