# Проблема с InsertionSort при сортировке 1000000 элементов массива

Tags: c#, сортировка, insert

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]На определенном этапе программа просто прекращает работу.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
 
class InsertionSort {
 
    // Функция сортировки массива с использованием сортировки вставкой
    void sort(int[] arr)
    {
        int n = arr.Length;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            int key = arr[i];
            int j = i - 1;
 
            // Переместить элементы arr [0..i-1], которые больше, чем key, на одну позицию впереди их текущей позиции
            while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            arr[j + 1] = key;
        }
    }
 
    // Функция для печати массива размера n
    static void printArray(int[] arr)
    {
        int n = arr.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
 
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
 
    // Запуск кода
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        int[] arr = new int[150000];
        Random rd = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; ++i){
            arr[i] = rd.Next(10,150001);
        }
        sw.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Given Array");
        printArray(arr);
        InsertionSort ob = new InsertionSort();
        //ob.sort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
        ob.sort(arr);
        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted array");
        printArray(arr);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted time= {0} ", (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0).ToString());
        sw.Reset();

    }
}
```

Comment: `На определенном` откройте уж секрет.

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Comment: aepot, ну я запускал в online gdb. Программа некоторое время выполняется(примерно минуту), потом останавливается и висит просто. Дальше выводит error 9 и все. Не знаю в чем проблема, мб с избытком памяти

Comment: `error9` и всё, совсем всё? наверняка там были ещё какие-то буквы, слова, предложения

Comment: А вообще у вас судя по всему `O(n^2)` получается, для такого числа элементов это, вероятно, просто долго будет вообще. Помимо ошибок.

Comment: CrazyElf
 да, только это. я чекнул это вроде run time error. И если можете, подскажите пжлст как упростить до О(n)?

Comment: CrazyElf
 дополнил скриншот выполнения программы

Comment: InsertionSort  является квадратичной сортировкой, нельзя от него ожидать быстрой работы на больших массивах. Другую сортировку используйте.

Comment: MBo
 я это понимаю, просто задание такое. нужно измерить время сортировки вставками для массива в 1000000 элементов :(

Comment: ОК, а может кто знает вообще примерно +- сколько времени insertion будет сортировать миллионный массив. хотя бы приблизительно

Comment: @chessmaster987, пусть на миллиард (10^9) операций уходит примерно секунда. Тогда на сортировку (10^6)^2 = 10^12 элементов уйдёт 10^(12-9) = 10^3 = 1000 секунд, но это нижняя грань, по факту будет больше, и возможно, в несколько раз

Comment: Пишете миллион, а в коде 150к. Где правда? Кстати, exit code 9 означает вот что https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901193/12888024

Comment: _а может кто знает вообще примерно +- сколько времени insertion будет сортировать миллионный массив_ - закомментируйте оба вызова `printArray`, вы никогда не дождетесь вывода миллиона чисел в консоль. `Sorted time= 1151,207`.

Comment: @aepot Я этот ответ тоже нагуглил, но там про линукс пишут. В windows тоже самое, это тоже out of memory?