# пусть к файлу через командную строку C#

Tags: c#, командная-строка

Допустим вот так всё отлично отрабатывает

```
var path = @"D:\FoxMinded\calculator-project\Calculator\numbersForCalculate.txt";
FromFile(path);
```

когда хочу передать путь к файлу через командную строку

код :

```
if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                var path = args[0];
                FromFile(path);
            }
```

в консоли :

```
"D:\hekeemje\calculator-project\Calculator\Calculator\bin\Debug\net5.0\Calculator.exe" "D:\hekeemje\calculator-project\Calculator\numbersForCalculate.txt"
```

тогда выбивает ошибку

```
Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Calculator.Program.FromFile(String path) in D:\FoxMinded\calculator-project\Calculator\Calculator\Program.cs:line 53
   at Calculator.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\FoxMinded\calculator-project\Calculator\Calculator\Program.cs:line 15
```

P.S. если пытаюсь сделать

```
var path = "D:\FoxMinded\calculator-project\Calculator\numbersForCalculate.txt";
```

тогда ругается и надо добавить "@"перед путем , может быть в этом проблема что в консоли оно принимает без "@" ?

Полностью код :

```
internal static class Program
    {
        private static readonly CalcOperations calculator = new CalcOperations();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                var path = args[0];
                FromFile(path);
            }
            else
            {
                while (true)
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Type what you need to calculate : ");
                string userText = Console.ReadLine();
                FromUser(userText);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void FromUser(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = calculator.ProcessStart(text);
                Console.WriteLine($"Result : {result}");
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You typed something wrong.");
            }
        }

        private static void FromFile(string path)
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                string[] str = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                var resultFile = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent + @"\resultOfCalculate.txt";

                using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(resultFile))
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            stream.WriteLine(str[i] + " = " + calculator.ProcessStart(str[i]));
                        }
                        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
                        {
                            stream.WriteLine(str[i] + " = " + ex.Message);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            stream.WriteLine(str[i] + " = You have mistake.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't find your file, please write correct way to file.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701431/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 как же пользоваться отладкой если я передаю это в командной строке без запущенной ide ?

Comment: ну так передавайте параметры с запущенной IDE (вы же можете под отладкой запускать ваш проект с параметрами). А ещё можете куда то вывести что ваща программа считвает как параметр, чтобы сравнить с тем, что у вас там должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

Уберите `public`.

От монстра `.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent` надо избавитья. Давайте так

```
var resultFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "resultOfCalculate.txt");
```

Файл результатов будет записан туда же, в ту же папку, откуда был прочитан исходный

И кавычки сами магическим образом никуда не денутся

```
var path = args[0].Trim('"');
```

Comment: ту же ошибку пишет 
вот может проблема в том что var path = "D:\FoxMinded\calculator-project\Calculator\numbersForCalculate.txt"; - даже так не пропускает если пишу в коде, надо обязательно добавить "@" перед путем , а когда я пишу через командную строку , тогда @ не используется и получается ошибка

Comment: @hekeemje собака - это только для литерала в C# коде. Командная строка - это не C#. Исправьте вопрос, покажите метод Main целиком. И вообще аргумент командной строки, который не содержит пробелов, не нужно брать в кавычки.

Comment: так же пробовал без кавычек всё делать , та же ошибка
P.S. добавил код полностью в вопросе

Comment: @hekeemje `public static void Main` - уберите `public`. И вот это что за монстр: `new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent`, откуда вам известно, что там достаточно родительских каталогов, вы хотя-бы в консоль выведите значение GetCurrentDirectory. Давайте так `var resultFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "resultOfCalculate.txt");`

Comment: заработало , а проблема всего лишь была в public , неожиданно
p.s. и спасибо за вариант с resultFile