# я хочу считать данные из текстового файла в двумерный массив но выводит ошибка ""индекс находился вне границ массива""

Tags: c#

static

```
void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.txt");
            int[,] num = new int[lines.Length, lines[0].Split(' ').Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] temp = lines[i].Split(' ');
                for (int j = 0; j < temp.Length; j++)
                    num[i, j] = int.Parse(temp[j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: подебадьте программу. в какой-то момент вы увидите, что у вас одна переменная больше, чем длина массива