# Доброго времени суток. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в логике консольной программы

Tags: c#

Прошу помочь найти ошибки в моей работе. При вводе значений получаются нули.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*Console.Write("Input x: ");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());*/

            Console.Write("Input a: ");
            double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Input b: ");
            double b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Input c: ");
            double c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            if (a != 1)
            {
                double discriminant = Math.Abs(Math.Pow(b, 2)) - 4 * a * c;
                if (discriminant > 0)
                {
                    double root_one = (b - (b * 2) - Math.Sqrt(discriminant))/2*a;
                    Console.WriteLine($"First root: {0}", root_one);
                    double root_two = (b - (b * 2) + Math.Sqrt(discriminant))/2*a;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Second root: {0}", root_two);
                } else if (discriminant == 0)
                {
                    double only_root = (b - (b * 2) - Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) /2*a;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Only root: {0}", only_root);
                } else if (discriminant < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There`s no roots in this equation");
                }

            }
            else if (a == 1)
            {
                double discriminant = Math.Abs(Math.Pow(b, 2)) - 4 * a * c;
                Console.WriteLine("Это приведенное квадратное уравнение");
                double root_one = (b - (b * 2) - Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / 2 * a;
                Console.WriteLine($"First root: {0}", root_one);
                double root_two = (b - (b * 2) + Math.Sqrt(discriminant)) / 2 * a;
                Console.WriteLine($"Second root: {0}", root_two);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас ошибка при выводе результата.

Смешаны два способа: старый, с позиционным расположением аргументов в операторе печати, и новый, задаваемый знаком доллара в начале строки.

Вы пишете:

```
           Console.WriteLine($"First root: {0}", root_one);
```

А надо так:

```
           Console.WriteLine($"First root: {root_one}");
```

Или, как справедливо подсказал в комментарии aepot, можно убоать знак `$` в начале строки:

```
           Console.WriteLine("First root: {0}", root_one);
```

Тогда всё получится:

[image: квадратное уравнение]

Comment: Или просто убрать `$`.