# Не считываются данные из файла c#

Tags: c#

Почему то пишет такую ошибку "Входная строка имела неверный формат данных". Не знаю в чем проблема. Я пробовала работать с файлом с расширением .dat, но все равно такая же ошибка.

```
    double[] dat;

    int N = 0;

    double[] p; 

    string header;

   private string[] title;

   public O()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        try 

        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr;
            sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\date.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            header = sr.ReadLine();
            N = Convert.ToInt16(sr.ReadLine());
            dat = new double[N];
            p = new double[N];
            title = new string[N];
            int i = 0; 
            string st;

            st = sr.ReadLine();
            while ((st != null) && (i < N))
            {
                title[i] = st;
                st = sr.ReadLine();
                dat[i++] = Convert.ToDouble(st); st = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();

            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Diagram);
            double sum = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) sum += dat[j];
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)

                p[j] = (double)(dat[j] / sum);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Диаграмма",

            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
    }
```

Comment: пользуйтесь отладчиком

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Comment: 1) в какой строке ошибка? 2) что во входном файле? покажите содержимое

Comment: Всем спасибо, я устранила ошибку, у меня файл был неверного формата.

Comment: Проблема в том, что не считывает русские буквы с файла, поставила латинские и заработало