# Пропадает введенный элемент массива

Tags: c#, консоль

есть задание "Дан массив чисел. Нужно его сдвинуть циклически на указанное пользователем значение позиций влево, не используя других массивов. Пример для сдвига один раз: {1, 2, 3, 4} => {2, 3, 4, 1}"

Написал код, но всегда из массива пропадает введенное число.

````
using System;

namespace SdvigMassive
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] massive;
            int massiveLength;
            int moveCount;
            int buffer1 = 0;
            int buffer2 = 0;
            int currentId;
            int targetId;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите длину массива:");
            if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out massiveLength))
            {
                massive = new int[massiveLength];

                Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив:");
                
                for (int i = 0; i < massive.Length; i++)
                {
                    massive[i] = i + 1;
                    Console.Write(massive[i] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nВведите сдвиг");

                if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out moveCount))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < moveCount; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = massive.Length; j > 0; j--)
                        {
                            targetId = j-1;
                            currentId = targetId + 1;
                            
                            if (currentId >= massive.Length)
                            {
                                currentId = 0;
                            }
                            
                            if (targetId < 0)
                            {
                                targetId = massive.Length;
                            }

                            if (buffer1 == 0)
                            {
                                buffer1 = massive[targetId];

                                massive[targetId] = massive[currentId];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                buffer2 = massive[targetId];
                                massive[targetId] = buffer1;
                                buffer1 = buffer2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                foreach (var number in massive)
                {
                    Console.Write(number + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладкой

Comment: Это делается одним циклом, а не двумя.