# Почему когда с новой формы пытаюсь получить данные из класса в родительской, получаю ссылку на NULL C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Имею класс с некоторыми полями:

```
        public class MicrocontrollerControl
    {
        public string name;
        public short[] Ports = new short[8]; 
        public string description;
    }
```

Инициализирую его в родительской форме:

```
public MicrocontrollerControl microcontrollerControl = new MicrocontrollerControl();
```

Заполняю созданный класс в событии двойного клика на грид и вызываю новую форму:

```
       private async void dGView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int cind = e.ColumnIndex;
        microcontrollerControl.description = null;
        if (cind == 1)
        {
            string id = dGView1.Rows[dGView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[dGView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString().Substring(13);//считываем id микроконтроллера и обрезаем чтобы получилось имя файла

            string md = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);//путь к Документам
            if (Directory.Exists(md + "\\PS_Aide") == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(md + "\\PS_Aide");//создаем папку в документах
            }
            md += "\\PS_Aide" + "\\"+id+".txt";

            FileStream fstream = null;
            try
            {
                fstream = new FileStream(md, FileMode.Open);
                // выделяем массив для считывания данных из файла
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fstream.Length];
                // считываем данные
                await fstream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                // декодируем байты в строку
              //  string textFromFile = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(buffer);//ncoding.GetEncoding(1251)

                byte countPort = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    byte type = 0;
                    byte Length = 0;
                    

                    if (buffer[i]==':') 
                    {
                        type = (byte)(buffer[++i].MyAsciiToHex()<<4);
                        type += buffer[++i].MyAsciiToHex();
                        Length = (byte)(buffer[++i].MyAsciiToHex() << 4);
                        Length += buffer[++i].MyAsciiToHex();
                        byte[] buff = new byte[Length];
                        if (type== 0x01)//00 имя 
                        {
                            for (byte j=0; j < Length;  j++)
                            {
                                ++i;
                                microcontrollerControl.name += ((char)buffer[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        if (type == 0x02 || type == 0x03 || type == 0x04 || type == 0x05 || type == 0x06 || type == 0x07 || type == 0x08 || type == 0x09)//PortABCDEFGH
                        {
                            short temp = 0;
                            byte ofs = 12;
                            for (byte j = 0; j < Length; j++)
                            {     
                                temp |= (short)((buffer[++i].MyAsciiToHex()) << ofs);
                                ofs -= 4;
                            }
                            microcontrollerControl.Ports[countPort] = temp;
                            ++countPort;
                        }
                        if (type == 0xff)//text
                        {
                            byte[] size = new byte[Length];
                            for (byte j = 0; j < Length; j++)
                            {
                                ++i;
                                size[j] += ((byte)buffer[i]);
                            }
                            microcontrollerControl.description += Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(size);
                        }
                        }
                }
                ControlMicrocontrolersForm controlMicrocontrolersForm = new ControlMicrocontrolersForm();
                controlMicrocontrolersForm.Owner = this;//устанавливаем владельца
                controlMicrocontrolersForm.Show();
```

И вот здесь при получении данных выдает ошибку(

```
    public partial class ControlMicrocontrolersForm : Form
{
    public ControlMicrocontrolersForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1 mainForm = this.Owner as Form1;
      
       listBox1.Items.Add( mainForm.microcontrollerControl.name + '\n');//вот здесь получаю ошибку

        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            DataGridStm.Rows[DataGridStm.Rows.Add()].Cells[0].Value = "Pin"+i;
        }

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы переменную `mainForm` устанавливаете в конструкторе, а строка  `controlMicrocontrolersForm.Owner = this` у вас после конструктора. Добавьте в конструктор `ControlMicrocontrolersForm` параметр через который вы будете передавать форму, выйдет как-то так:

```
public ControlMicrocontrolersForm(Form1 mainForm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
  
    listBox1.Items.Add( mainForm.microcontrollerControl.name + '\n');

    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        DataGridStm.Rows[DataGridStm.Rows.Add()].Cells[0].Value = "Pin"+i;
    }

}
```

Вызов из родительской формы:

```
ControlMicrocontrolersForm controlMicrocontrolersForm = new ControlMicrocontrolersForm(this);
controlMicrocontrolersForm.Show();
```