# Не выводится ответ в консоль С#

Tags: c#, .net

Моя проблема заключается  в том, что консоль не выводит мне ответ, никак. Что бы я не менял (только код не переписывал), прошу помочь, дать ответ, почему не выводится результат и как его вывести. (Ошибок при компиляции нет, как и эксепшнов в рантайме, мистика)

```
/*
На вход идёт 3х-значное число, которое мы разбиваем на 3 цифры,
которые разбили на две суммы. 1го и 2го, 2го и 3го.
Например, число "123" из него получаем 2 суммы "1 + 2 = 3" и "2 + 3 = 5",
после мы должны вывести 2 суммы в порядке убывания, как в данном случае "53".
Главный вопрос - какое наименьшее трёхзначное число даст на выходе "1412"?
(вывести это число) 
*/

class Program
{
    public static void MyFunction() 
    {
        for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            string Str = Convert.ToString(i); //Перевожу числовое i в строку, чтобы разбить посимвольно.
            char[] Arr = Str.ToCharArray(); // Разбиваю
            int Sum1 = (int)Arr[0] + (int)Arr[1];
            int Sum2 = (int)Arr[1] + (int)Arr[2];
            string FirstRes = Convert.ToString(Math.Max(Sum1, Sum2)); // Беру большую из сумм
            string SecondRes = Convert.ToString(Math.Min(Sum1, Sum2)); // Меньшую из сумм
            string Result = FirstRes + SecondRes;
            if (Result == "1412") // Условие выполнения
            {
                int OutputResult = i;
                Console.WriteLine(OutputResult);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyFunction();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Постарался поподробнее всё расписать от условия, что в комментарии в коде, до комментария строк кода. Надеюсь, что мне смогут помочь с моей (скорее всего тривиальной, но кто не был новичком) проблемой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: Скорее всего в условие просто не входит....возьмите отладчик и посмотрите ↑↑↑

Comment: Зачем вы опять делаете массив символов из строки? Строка это и есть массив символов, и работать с ней можно точно так же как с массивом. Разница только в том, что строку изменить нельзя, а массив можно. Но вам и не надо менять, верно?

Comment: Почему нельзя сразу введённое значение преобразовать в число и затем выделить первую, вторую и третью цифру?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы не учли, что при приведении char к int вы получите не цифру, а ее код [по таблице ASCII](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg). Поэтому на первой же итерации цикла вы получаете число 9796. По этой причине ваше условие не выполнится никогда. Поэтому ничего и не выводится.

Если хотите получить сами цифры, а не их коды, то вам нужно вычесть 48 (код символа `0` по таблице ASCII ) из каждого полученного кода символа:

```
class Program
{
    public static void MyFunction() 
    {
        for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            string Str = Convert.ToString(i); //Перевожу числовое i в строку, чтобы разбить посимвольно.
            char[] Arr = Str.ToCharArray(); // Разбиваю
            int Sum1 = (int)Arr[0] + (int)Arr[1] - 96; // 48*2, т.к. два числа
            int Sum2 = (int)Arr[1] + (int)Arr[2] - 96; // 48*2, т.к. два числа
            string FirstRes = Convert.ToString(Math.Max(Sum1, Sum2)); // Беру большую из сумм
            string SecondRes = Convert.ToString(Math.Min(Sum1, Sum2)); // Меньшую из сумм
            string Result = FirstRes + SecondRes;
            if (String.Equals(Result, "1412")) // Условие выполнения
            {
                int OutputResult = i;
                Console.WriteLine(OutputResult);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyFunction();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему 48?...

Comment: @aepot, код символа `0` по таблице ASCII

Comment: Это стоит добавить в ответ

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за совет, добавил