# Exception: "message было null."

Tags: c#, .net-core

Пишу бота на telegram.bots, все было нормально, пока вдруг он просто перестал принимать сообщения.
При запуске просто шлёт exception "message было null."
Пишу так:

```
    async private static Task Update(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken token)
{
    var message = update.Message;
    string isResponsed = " [responsed]";

    if (message.Text != null)
    {
      //do smthng
    } 
}
```

Comment: проверь, что message не null

Comment: @goodmice так я же проверяю

Comment: Вам же пишут проверить message а не message.Text

Comment: `if (message.Text != null)` => `if (message?.Text != null)`

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)