# Pong game. Мяч проходит через ракетку

Tags: c#

Иногда мяч проходит через ракетку (обычно когда очень часто нажимаются кнопки управления или они зажимаются). Особенно это заметно, если увеличить Thread.Sleep() (также появляется inputlag)

```
public class Player
{
    public int X { set; get; }
    public int Y { set; get; }
    public int Lenght {set; get; }
    int mapHeight;
    public Player(int x, int mapHeight)
    {
        this.mapHeight = mapHeight;
        X = x;
        Y = mapHeight / 2;
        Lenght = mapHeight / 3;
    }
     public void Write()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        for(int i=(Y-(Lenght/2));i<(Y+(Lenght/2));i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, i);
            Console.Write("│");
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
    public void Up()
    {
        if((Y-1-(Lenght/2))!=0)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, (Y + (Lenght / 2)) - 1);
            Console.Write(" ");
            Y--;
            Write();
        }
    }
    public void Down()
    {
        if ((Y + Lenght - (Lenght / 2)) != mapHeight+2)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(X, (Y -(Lenght / 2)));
            Console.Write(" ");
            Y++;
            Write();
        }
    }
}
введите  public class Map
{
    public int Height { set; get; }
    public int Width { set; get; }
    public Map()
    {
        Height = 20;
        Width = 60;
    }
    public Map(int width, int height)
    {
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
    }
    public void Write()
    {
        for (int i=1; i<=Width; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 0);
            Console.Write("‒");
        } // Верхняя граница
        for (int i = 1; i <= Width; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(i, (Height + 1));
            Console.Write("‒");
        } // Нижняя граница
        for (int i = 1; i <= Height; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
            Console.Write("│");
        } // Левая граница
        for (int i = 1; i <= Height; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Width+1, i);
            Console.Write("│");
        } // Правая граница
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.Write("┌");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Width+1, 0);
        Console.Write("┐");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Height+1);
        Console.Write("└");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Width+1, Height+1);
        Console.Write("┘");
    }
}
public class Ball
{
    public int X { set; get; }
    public int Y { set; get; }
  public  int rotationX;
  public  int rotationY;
   public int i;
    public int mapHeight;
    public int mapWidth;
    public int route { set; get; }
    public Ball (int x, int y, int mapHeight, int mapWidth)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        this.mapHeight = mapHeight;
        this.mapWidth= mapWidth;
        rotationX = -1;
        rotationY = 1;
    }
    public void Logic(Player player1, Player player2)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
        Console.Write(" ");
        if(Y<=1||Y>=mapHeight)
        {
            rotationY *= -1;

        }
        if (((X == 3 || X == mapWidth - 3) && (player1.Y - (player1.Lenght / 2)) <= Y && (player1.Y + (player1.Lenght / 2)) > Y))
        {
            rotationX *= -1;
            if (Y == player1.Y)
            {
                route = 0;

            }
            if ((Y >= (player1.Y - (player1.Lenght / 2)) && Y <= player1.Y) || (Y > player1.Y && Y < (player1.Y + (player1.Lenght / 2))))
            {
                route = 1;
            }
        }
            switch(route)
            {
                case 0:
            X += rotationX;
            break;
            case 1:
                    X += rotationX;
                    Y += rotationY;
                    break;

            }
        
    }
    public void Write()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(X, Y);
        Console.Write("■");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;


    }
}
public class Pong
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public Map map;
    Player player1;
    Player player2;
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    ConsoleKey consoleKey;
    Ball ball;
    public Pong(int width, int height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        map = new Map(width, height);
        ball = new Ball(width / 2, height / 2, height, width) ;
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Init();
            map.Write();
            player1.Write();
            player2.Write();
            ball.Write();
            while(ball.X!=1&&ball.X!=width-1)
            {
                ControlInput();
                switch(consoleKey)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.W:
                        player1.Up();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.S:
                        player1.Down(); 
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        player2.Up();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        player2.Down();
                        break;
                }
                consoleKey = ConsoleKey.A;
                ball.Logic(player1, player2);
                ball.Write();
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }

    }
    public void Init()
    {
        player1 = new Player(2, height);
        player2 = new Player(width-2, height);
        keyInfo = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
        consoleKey = new ConsoleKey();
        ball.X = width / 2;
        ball.Y=height / 2;
        ball.route = 0;
    }
   public void ControlInput ()
    {
        if(Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            consoleKey = keyInfo.Key;
        }
    }
}
Console.CursorVisible = false;
Pong pong = new Pong(60, 20);
pong.Start();
Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: Мяч проходит через ракетку, не засчитывается попадание по мячу]

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Comment: [Сведения об отладке кода C# с помощью Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger)