# Пытаюсь нарисовать график сердца по формуле (x2 + y2 – 1)3 – x2y3 = 0, выдаёт system.overflowexception: "ошибка переполнения."

Tags: c#, winforms, график

```
    Panel panel;
    float Amplitude = 1.0F;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // закрепляем минимальный размер окна

        this.MinimumSize = new Size(1000, 00);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        // используем "табличную верстку"
        TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        panel = new Panel()
        {
            Location = new Point(5, 5),
            Size = new Size(ClientSize.Width - 10, ClientSize.Height - 10),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill // заполняет все пространство 1 столбика tableLayoutPanel
        };

        // первая панель должна поддерживать рисование Paint

        panel.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel_Paint);

        // при изменении размеров окна, а значит и панели, перерисовывать график
        panel.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(panel_SizeChanged);

        // устанавливает цвет фона панели
        panel.BackColor = Color.White;

        // панели добавляем в tableLayoutPanel1
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel, 0, 0);

        Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);

    }

    private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Graphics g = this.panel.CreateGraphics();
        List<Coord> points = new List<Coord>();
        float x = 0, y = 0;

        // соотносим амплитуду с высотой панели
        float multiplier = Amplitude * panel.Height / 10;

        // вычисляем координаты х и у синуса и добавляем их в коллекцию points
        for (float i = -panel.Width / 2; i < panel.Width / 2; i += 0.1f)
        {
            x = i;
            y = (float)(multiplier * (1/2)*Math.Pow(x, 2/3)+Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 4/3)+4*(1-Math.Pow(x, 2))));

            points.Add(new Coord(x, y));
        }
        // устанавливаем цвет и размер "пера" для рисования осей
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3F);

        // устанавливаем цвет и размер "пера" для рисования сетки
        Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1F);

        // если рисовать оси отдельно, см. коммент, то при перерисовке не всегда аккуратно
        // можно откомментировать и попробовать
        //g.DrawLine(pen, 0, panel.Height / 2, panel.Width, panel.Height / 2);
        // g.DrawLine(pen, panel.Width / 2, 0, panel.Width / 2, panel.Height);
        // поэтому
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            k++;
            if (k != 6)
            { // рисуем сетку
                g.DrawLine(pen1, i * panel.Width / 10, 0, i * panel.Width / 10,
               panel.Height);
            }
            else
            {
                // рисуем ось
                g.DrawLine(pen, panel.Width / 2, 0, panel.Width / 2, panel.Height);
            }
        }
        k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            k++;
            if (k != 6)
            {
                // рисуем сетку
                g.DrawLine(pen1, 0, i * panel.Height / 10, panel.Width, i *
               panel.Height / 10);
            }
            else
            {
                // рисуем ось
                g.DrawLine(pen, 0, panel.Height / 2, panel.Width, panel.Height / 2);
            }

        }
        // рисуем маркеры
        for (int i = 0; i < panel.Width; i += panel.Width / 50)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen1, i, panel.Height / 2 - 3, i, panel.Height / 2 + 3);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < panel.Height; i += panel.Height / 50)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen1, panel.Width / 2 - 3, i, panel.Width / 2 + 3, i);
        }
        // задаем "кисть" для отрисовки графика синуса по координатам points
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            **g.FillEllipse(brush, (int)points[i].X + panel.Width / 2, -(int)points[i].Y+ panel.Height / 2, 2, 2); //Вот здесь выдаёт** ошибку
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Добавьте ошибку в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил, строка кода с ошибкой почти в самом конце, выделить просто не получается

Comment: Нужен полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)