# Выход за массив в алгоритме деления

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Не понимаю почему выхожу за массив.

```
public void Div_Polynomials(double[] pol1, double[] pol2, CancellationToken cancelToken) //деление полинмов  
    { 


        double[] quotient = { }; // делимое 
        double[] mod = { }; // остаток от деления 

        int size_quotient = pol1.Length - pol2.Length; 
        int size_mod = pol2.Length - 1; 
        //pol1.Length - n 
        //pol2.Length - m 
        Array.Resize(ref quotient, size_quotient); 
        Array.Resize(ref mod, size_mod); 
        size_quotient = size_quotient + 1; 
        size_mod = size_mod + 1; //может быть непраивльно 
        /* 
        void division(int* arr1, int n, int* arr2, int m, int* result, int&nm) { 
            for (int k = (n - m); k >= 0; k--) 
            { 
                result[k] = arr1[k + m] / arr2[m]; 
                for (int j = k + m - 1; j >= k; j--) 
                    arr1[j] -= arr2[j - k] * result[k]; 
            } 
        } 
        */ 

        for (int k = size_quotient-1; k >= 0 && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested; k--) //+ 
        { //первый многочлен 
            quotient[k] = pol1[pol2.Length - 1 + k] / pol2[pol2.Length - 1]; // коэфи 
            for (int j = pol2.Length + k - 1; j >= k; j--) 
            {  //второй многчлен  
                pol1[j] = pol1[j] - quotient[k] * pol2[j - k]; 
            } 
        } 
        int g = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size_mod - 1; i++) 
        { //остаток 
            mod[i] = pol1[i]; 
            g++; 
        } 

      
        result_polynomial = quotient; 
        result_quotient = quotient; 
        result_mod = mod; 
    }
```

Comment: Текст ошибки???

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)

Comment: Выхожу за массив в в этой строчке  quotient[k] = pol1[pol2.Length - 1 + k] / pol2[pol2.Length - 1];

Comment: `pol1[pol2.Length - 1 + k]` => `pol1[pol2.Length - 1 - k]` ?

Answer (score 1):

В массиве длины `Length` элементы индексируются от `0` до `Length - 1`.

Вы создаете массив `double[] quotient` длины `size_quotient`:

```
Array.Resize(ref quotient, size_quotient);
```

Затем вы этот `size_quotient` (*зачем-то?*) увеличиваете на 1 (**длина массива при этот остается равна "старому" значению `size_quotient`!**):

```
size_quotient = size_quotient + 1;
```

Но цикл у вас начинается с `int k = size_quotient - 1`:

```
for (int k = size_quotient-1; k >= 0 && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested; k--) //+ 
{
    quotient[k] = pol1[pol2.Length - 1 + k] / pol2[pol2.Length - 1];
    // ...
}
```

В итоге на первой итерации вы обращаетесь к элементу `Length` массива `quotient` и получаете закономерное исключение `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Как исправить? Зависит от логики вашего алгоритма:

1. Либо нужно просто **удалить строчку** `size_quotient = size_quotient + 1;`
2. Либо нужно создавать массив `quotient` уже увеличенного на 1 размера: **`Array.Resize(ref quotient, size_quotient + 1);`** (можно просто перенести строку `size_quotient = size_quotient + 1;` до строки `Array.Resize(...)`)
3. Либо изменить инициализацию переменной цикла на: **`for (int k = size_quotient - 2; ...)`**.