# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта, работа с БД

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

Есть база данных и WPF приложение. Хочу на странице добавить в базу данных новую строку, но при проверке на заполненность полей происходит ошибка, "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". При этом в идентичном проекте с таким же кодом всё работает.

```
    private ReaderCard currentReader = new ReaderCard();

        public ReaderCardEdit(ReaderCard selectedReaderCard)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (currentReader != null)
            {
                currentReader = selectedReaderCard;
            }

            DataContext = currentReader;
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.GoBack();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentReader.LastName))
            {
                errors.Append("Введите фамилию \n");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentReader.FirstName))
            {
                errors.Append("Введите имя \n");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentReader.Address))
            {
                errors.Append("Введите адрес");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentReader.Phone))
            {
                errors.Append("Введите телефон \n");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentReader.DateOfBirth.ToString()))
            {
                errors.Append("Введите дату рождения");
            }
        }
```

Таблица с читателями называется ReaderCard. Скрин ошибки прикрепляю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Метод `ReaderCardEdit` выглядит подозрительно. Либо проверяется не то, либо присваивается не то (либо и то и другое). Очень странно проверять что-то что оно не `null`, а потом присваивать не то, что проверялось, в другую переменную, а наоборот тому, что проверялось, что-то присваивать в случае, если оно не `null`. Вангую, что в `selectedReaderCard` у вас `null`, а вы это не проверяете и в `currentReader` оказывается тоже `null` в результате. (Изначально там не `null`, а `new ReaderCard()`, поэтому условие срабатывает.)

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, не знаю как я это не заметил. Проверяться должен selectedReaderCard, если он null то как раз создаётся новый объект, если нет то редактируется существующая строка. А получилось что если добавляю новый то сам же ему null и присваиваю. Спасибо ещё раз

Comment: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)