# Корабли в морском бою странно отображаются на поле С#

Tags: c#

На поле отображается только последний добавленный в список корабль. Такое ощущение, что поле сбрасывает координаты всех других кораблей, кроме последнего.

Вот коды:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sea_Battle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BattleField field = new BattleField();
            field.PlaceShips();
            field.PrintArea();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс корабля:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sea_Battle
{
    class Ship
    {
        public bool Horizontal { get; private set; }
        public int SizeX {  get; private set; }
        public int SizeY {  get; private set; }
        public List<int[]> Coords { get; private set; }
        public List<int[]> ShotCoords { get; set; }
        public Ship(int size)
        {
            Random fiftyfifty = new Random();
            Coords = new List<int[]>();
            ShotCoords = new List<int[]>();
            if (fiftyfifty.Next(0, 2) == 0)
            {
                Horizontal = true;
                SizeX = size; 
                SizeY = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Horizontal = false;
                SizeX = 1;
                SizeY = size;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс игрового поля:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sea_Battle
{
    class BattleField
    {
        string[] letters = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K" };
        char[,] visibleArea = new char[10, 10];
        bool[,] hiddenArea = new bool[10, 10];
        List<Ship> shipList = new List<Ship>();
        public void PlaceShips()
        {
            Ship odnushka1 = new Ship(1);
            Ship odnushka2 = new Ship(1);
            Ship odnushka3 = new Ship(1);
            Ship odnushka4 = new Ship(1);

            Ship dvushka1 = new Ship(2);
            Ship dvushka2 = new Ship(2);
            Ship dvushka3 = new Ship(2);

            Ship treshka1 = new Ship(3);
            Ship treshka2 = new Ship(3);

            Ship chetire = new Ship(4);

            shipList.Add(odnushka1); 
            shipList.Add(odnushka2);
            shipList.Add(odnushka3);
            shipList.Add(odnushka4);
            shipList.Add(dvushka1);
            shipList.Add(dvushka2);
            shipList.Add(dvushka3);
            shipList.Add(treshka1);
            shipList.Add(treshka2);
            shipList.Add(chetire);
            foreach (Ship ship in shipList)
            {
                PlaceShip(ship);
                Console.WriteLine("jvlisdbgv");
            }
        }
        void PlaceShip(Ship ship)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int row, col;
            if (ship.Horizontal)
            {
                row = r.Next(0, 10);
                col = r.Next(0, 11 - ship.SizeX);
            }
            else
            {
                row = r.Next(0, 11 - ship.SizeY);
                col = r.Next(0, 10);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ship.SizeX; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ship.SizeY; j++)
                {
                    hiddenArea[col + i, row + j] = true;
                    ship.Coords.Add(new int[] { col + i, row + j });
                }
            }
        }
        public void PrintArea()
        {
            string areaString = "  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n";
            for (int i = 0;  i < 10; i++)
            {
                areaString += $"{letters[i]} ";
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    if (visibleArea[i, j] == '\0')
                    {
                        visibleArea[i, j] = '~';
                    }
                    if (hiddenArea[i, j]) visibleArea[i, j] = 'O';
                    areaString += $"{visibleArea[i,j]} ";
                }
                areaString += "\n";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(areaString);
        }
    }
}
```

Консоль выводит:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
B ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
C ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
D ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
E O ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
F O ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
G O ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
H O ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
J ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
K ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Как видно, на экран выводится только четырёхплубный корабль. Я пробовал его убрать, но выводился последний созданный корабль. Видимо что-то не так с методом PrintArea()

Comment: Попробовал запустить, результат показывает все корабли, хоть и неправильно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: код работает. но корабли не так стоЯт