Ничего не выводится
По задумке в текстбокс должен построково выводиться весь текст из файла.
if (File.Exists(body))
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(body, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {      
                while (reader.Peek() > -1)
                {

                    textBox1.Text += reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


А в чем смысл читать построчно и собирать файл с кучей аллокаций, да еще в гуи потоке, когда можно просто полностью прочитать файл за раз и вывести его в текстовом поле

Код рабочий. Разве что будет выводить всё в одну строку. И не постепенно, а всё разом, потому что GUI обновится только когда произойдёт выход из метода.

textBox1.Text = File.Exists(body) ? File.ReadAllLines(body) : string.Empty; - вот и весь ваш код... А еще лучше, awit File.ReadAllLinesAsync(body). А так, как и сказали выше, ваш код рабочий, занимайтесь отладкой.

Точки останова, отладка, не? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/373567

Новая строка
textBox1.Text += reader.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Для начала нужно сделать так:
textBox1.Text = File.Exists(body) ? File.ReadAllText(body) : "Файл не найден";

Строки из файла будут отображаться в одну строку. Если необходимо отображение построчно, то нужно установить свойство textBox1.Multiline = true и увеличить высоту текстбокса, а можно и полосы прокрутки отобразить.

ReadAllText :)

@aepot Ну да, ну да. Можно и textBox1.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(body), но всем текстом будет быстрее, наверное.
